# Visio VBA : Connect a line shape to two other shapes

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio

I am dropping shapes on my Page via VBA UserForms. Amongst others I need to drop a "curved line" shape which should connect two specified shapes.

I found out how to directly create a connection [here](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s394/lines-connectors.htm) but I want the shape from my specific master because it has some custom Data Properties.

I expected there to be some Fields in the DataSheet of the Connector-Shape where I could reference the start and end shapes? could not find anything more helpful.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa201778(v=office.10))

```
Dim shp As Visio.Shape 'connector
Dim src As Visio.Shape 'connect this
Dim aim As Visio.Shape 'to this

[...] 'Set shape variables

shp.Cells("BeginX").GlueTo src.Cells("PinX")
shp.Cells("EndX").GlueTo aim.Cells("PinX")
```